# What is center-pane-element in Primefaces Layout?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use Primefaces layout, but I get this following error. I googled the error, but I don't see much help elsewhere in the internet.

> UI Layout Initialization Error
>
> The center-pane element does not exist.
>
> The center-pane is a required element

What is a center-pane?

Below is the code I have have in my xhtml file.

```
 <p:layout >  

<p:layoutUnit position="north" >  
    <h:outputText value="North unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response is in the answer , if you use the `<p:layout>` type you need to specify a center layout like that :

```
<p:layout >  
<p:layoutUnit position="north" >  
    <h:outputText value="North unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit id="centerLayout" position="center">
 CONTENT 
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In dialogs in version 6.2 - the fix suggested here does nothing.  Instead, this seems to be a bug in Primefaces 6.2 and has been answered here: [UI Layout Initialization Error PrimeFaces 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980465/ui-layout-initialization-error-primefaces-6-2)